# How do I reset PHPStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

My problem is that I can't continue with my project, as long as PHPStorm won't let me use key combination anymore. Some key combination like ctrl + c are still working, but other more important combinations like uncomment many lines, or indent the code and some others don't work anymore. That's since yesterday, where my computer just shuts down without a reason.

Does anybody know how do I reset the settings of PHPStorm? I don't really want to uninstall and reinstall the program.

Using: PHPStorm 9.0.2

Comment: did you try : https://www.google.com/search?q=reset+PHPstorm ?

Comment: of course I did and I found some thing I can do to reset the settings. I did what they said but it just did nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Menu `Preferences`, in the Preferences window choose `Keymap` and select one of the preset keymaps, reset or delete current one.

[image]

Comment: well I took the netbeans keymap.. it's a little bit different but worked for me :) thanks